# Automatic NSView resizing

Tags: cocoa, nstableview, nsview, autoresize

I'm doing something with cocoa which I think is a bit complicate for a beginner like me. I tried a few things, but I admit I need some theory first, because I would like to understand exactly the meaning of this concepts.

I see that every NSView and every class that subclasses it has one thing called `frame`, and one called `bounds`. They both have a size with width and height and an origin.

I have an NSView with an NSTableView inside of it. 
I have the size of a row from the table view, and I would like to set the height of both NSView and NSTableView equal to `rows*rowSize`, in a way that the group NSView+subviews is automatically resized when an object is added or removed to and from the data source of the Table View.

I made some experiments, but I did end a bit confused about frame, bounds, sizes and so on. I don't know what I should change and how.

Can you please give me an hint about what bounds and frame basically are, and how can I achieve that magic resizing?

Thank you for your replies in advance. Best regards,

—Albé

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The difference between *frame* and *bounds* is covered very nicely in the [View Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaViewsGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002978) (under View Geometry).

You'll also want to peruse the [NSView Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSView_Class/Reference/NSView.html), where you'll find some handy notifications, such as `NSViewFrameDidChangeNotification` and handy methods such as `setPostsFrameChangedNotifications:`.